# Reference Error, angular is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower, yeoman-generator-angular, referenceerror

I've sat all morning trying to fix this issue with Angular.

I've generated a project with yeoman (in fact, like a thousand of them today...) and it just won't start, it keeps giving me the

```
ReferenceError: angular is not defined error
```

Ok, before I put the code in, I have tried with npm install, bower install, with and without sudo.

I've added the wiredep task to the Gulpfile, I've hardcoded the dependencies in the index.html file in all different sectors of it, and tried a number of workarounds that have worked for other people in this website and others, nothing seems to work for me though :(

I guess it must be a silly mistake, but I just can't get to it...

So, here's the code:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="newOneApp">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div class="header">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">newOne</a>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a ng-href="#/about">About</a></li>
              <li><a ng-href="#/">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> from the Yeoman team</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
     <script>
       !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
       (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
       r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
       }(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

The app.js:

```
'use strict';
angular
  .module('newOneApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'about'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

The main.js:

```
'use strict';


angular.module('newOneApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function () {
    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  });
```

And finally, the about.js:

```
'use strict';

    angular.module('newOneApp')
      .controller('AboutCtrl', function () {
        this.awesomeThings = [
          'HTML5 Boilerplate',
          'AngularJS',
          'Karma'
        ];
      });
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure your build process is loading `angular.js` or `angular.min.js` onto your webpage?

Comment: You should load scripts in after the closed body tag

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I don't really know that I'm sure what you mean, I've ran gulp build and nothing strange happened if that's where you're heading

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for reply, that don't do the trick either

Comment: Could you try `view page source` and click the link to `angular.js` and see if the angular file is actually loaded?

Comment: Hi Evans, thank you for elaborating there, I am a newbie in angular (real newbie, just a few days on it)
  
 The answer is no, it doesn't show up, I managed to narrow the issue down to that yesterday, it seems to be that the routes of my folders aren't picked up when the projects build, which is quite odd as the project builds itself automatically with yo angular

Answer (score 0):

I believe `<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>` (and maybe the other angular libraries) should be in the header of your index.html.

Comment: He has a builder system which presumably automatically injects dependencies such as angular. I do suspect the problem may be in there.

Comment: Yes, I'm not familiar with Yeoman but I can reproduce that same error moving the script src on a test project from the header to below the body.

Comment: its faster to load scripts after the body has rendered, they don't need to be in the header

Comment: Hi, thank you for replies, that isn't working either, I already tried it earlier on, and again now just for in case, not working :(

Answer (score 0):

We've actually had issues with this before.

Our issue was that our build system put a `defer` tag onto some scripts, but not others. This caused our Angular files to load before angular.js could load itself.

Either way, it seems like a problem with your build system. I would post the Yeoman code too. What does your actual *rendered* page look like? Does it have `angular.js` on it? Does the script tag have a `defer` attribute?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, no the rendered page doesn't look like others I've created with yeoman, it's more simple.

None of my js files have defer attributes, they are all clean as I just created them